# Why are MaxIdleConns and MaxIdleConnsPerHost not strictly respected?

Tags: go

I am running an application that makes large numbers of `http.Get` calls. I only have a limited number of workers, but because of the rate of the requests, the leak of `TIME_WAIT` connections resulted in eventual `Cannot assign requested address` errors.

Using netstat, I could see the number of connections getting up near the 30K range, before the errors started.

After some googling, I switched to my own HTTP client, where I configured a transport with `MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 100`.

This has helped. However, it's not behaving the way I would expect. Here are my observations/questions:

1. If I switch it to use `MaxIdleConns` instead, it doesn't work, and the connection leak just keeps exploding. Why does `MaxIdleConns` seemingly get completely ignored? It'd make more sense to have a strict total limit, rather than something that builds in a sneaky potential multiplier (real_max = configured_limit * variable_number_of_remote_hosts).
2. I notice in the net/http docs that the actual default for `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` is 2. It looks like that gets ignored as well. In fact, if I set it to any low number like 5, it still gets ignored. Why is that?
3. By design, my requests get redirected and the client follows the `302`. I notice that the idle connection limit to my ORIGINAL destination is respected (they're sitting at 100), but connections to nodes it redirects to do NOT adhere to the max, even though they're also idle (or at least, showing up as `TIME_WAIT` in netstat). If I break them down by host (ip:port), I see ONE destination at `100`, and the other relevant ones (that it redirects to) in the thousands.

In general: what's the correct way to configure a Go http client to properly limit "max idle conns" in all cases?

Comment: Are you reading and closing the response bodies? Can you [show the relevant code that produces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Might be difficult to pull out a minimal reproducible code chunk, but I do "defer closeBody(body); return io.Copy(out, body)" in all cases (closeBody just calls close and prints something if close returns error).

Comment: How large is the worker pool? Do the workers share the http client? How many different hosts are you connecting (being redirected) to? Have you verified that the server(s) don't send "Connection: close" in the response header?

Comment: Also, it seems to me like this may not be clear to you: connections in the TIME_WAIT state are not idle. They have been closed by one or both sides.

Comment: 100 workers sharing the same http client. For context, I'm reading from an HDFS cluster - one name node, 3 workers (so 3 destinations to redirect to).

Interesting re: TIME_WAIT - does that imply there's a bug (e.g. I'm not fully reading the response before closing, or I'm not closing the response body)? I'm pretty sure they're all being closed, and io.Copy seems to pull all the data out.